# fill the tuples from core data

Tags: swift, core-data, tuples

I do not understand how to fill a tuple cameras with data from core data
I'm only filling in the last values from core data

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "MarkersModel", in: context)


    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "MarkersModel")

    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    do {
        let result = try context.fetch(request)
        for data in result as! [NSManagedObject] {
            print(data.value(forKey: "nameCam") as! String)
            print(data.value(forKey: "urlCam") as! String)

            cameras = [(data.value(forKey: "nameCam") as! String, data.value(forKey: "urlCam") as! String)]

        }
    } catch {
        print("Failed")
    }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to append a new tuple for each object fetched from Core Data. To avoid having to use valueForKey I modified the fetch request declaration

```
let request: NSFetchRequest<MarkersModel> = MarkersModel.fetchRequest()
request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

do {
    let result = try context.fetch(request)
    for data in result {
        print(data.nameCam)
        print(data.urlCam)

        cameras.append((data.nameCam, data.urlCam))
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}}
```

Comment: Thanks brother!  You saved my time! I didn't even think that is possible it(append) to use